# Update table with stored procedure results in error

Tags: c#, sql, xslt, stored-procedures

I have a SQL stored procedure for updating my table. But when executing the query via C#, xslt the one of the columns deleted from the table.

My stored procedure is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[kt_editingnotes]
    (@NOTE NVARCHAR (512),
     @ITEMNUMBER NVARCHAR (512),
     @ACCOUNT NVARCHAR (512),
     @CODE NVARCHAR(512)
    )
AS
  UPDATE NOTES 
  SET TXT = @NOTE 
  WHERE NOTESRECID = (SELECT ISP_EFAVORITLINE.ROWNUMBER 
                      FROM ISP_EFAVORITLINE 
                      WHERE ISP_EFAVORITLINE.ACCOUNT = @ACCOUNT 
                        AND ISP_EFAVORITLINE.ITEMNUMBER = @ITEMNUMBER 
                        AND ISP_EFAVORITLINE.CODE = @CODE)
  return
```

and I am calling it like this:

```
ExecStoredProcedure('kt_editingnotes', concat('@ITEMNUMBER:', $ITEMNUMBER,', @ACCOUNT:', $ACCOUNT,', @CODE:', $CODE))
```

What is the problem? Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: @Arshad no error geting but the field don't updaing.but that field will removed from the table>>

Comment: i don't see where you are passing the notes parameter to the stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

editingI noticed in the `ExecStoredProcedure` that you execute the procedure `'kt_deletenotes'` instead of `'kt_editingnotes'`. Try changing the line where you call your procedure to call the correct procedure.

```
ExecStoredProcedure('kt_editingnotes', concat('@ITEMNUMBER:', $ITEMNUMBER,', @ACCOUNT:', $ACCOUNT,', @CODE:', $CODE))
```

Comment: Sorry My mistaken .In my code I already write like that ..Kt_editingnotes....When I copy and paste SP here then I had mistaken .